# Rendering cyrillic fonts from html page to pdf in django project

Tags: django

I am trying to render an hmtl page in russian to pdf. Everything works fine except for russian fonts. The resulting pdf page shows either black squares or trash.

That's my html to pdf page:

```
{% load static %}
 <style>
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: 
        url({% static 'webfonts/OpenSans-regular.ttf' %})format('truetype');
 }
 body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
 }
 </style>
<body>
олывоалыовалоылвоа <br>
олыолваолыоалывоалы
</body>
```

That,s my project tree:
-project/static/webfonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf

Please, help

Comment: Does the ttf file support cyrillian characters?

Comment: As far as I understand, yes. I loaded cyrillic fonts from google fonts